Integration android studio with socket.io
I created a basic android project (Gradle/kts,version 8.6.0, AGP 8.4.0).
I followed a tutorial asking for a change in build.gradle file (below).
in dependencies section :
    implementation("io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3") {
        exclude() group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

Is there a public repository integrated with android studio ?
I have never been able to make it to work.
You would be my hero if you could fix it.
Thanks
I am simply expecting to get the socket.io library added to my project and build my project
The okhttp library works fine within build.gradle.

https://pastebin.com/bud5q1t8   the build.gradle.kts
